# FlSpot data Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, fl-chart

I use FL Chart in my Flutter Apps
but i too many repeat my code, can i make it to use i++

here my code

```dart
    final LineChartBarData lineChartBarData1 = LineChartBarData(
      spots: [        
        FlSpot(00.00, (dataAcc[50]['x'] / 1.00)),
        FlSpot(01.00, (dataAcc[49]['x'] / 1.00)),
        FlSpot(02.00, (dataAcc[48]['x'] / 1.00)),
        FlSpot(03.00, (dataAcc[47]['x'] / 1.00)),
        FlSpot(04.00, (dataAcc[46]['x'] / 1.00)),
        FlSpot(05.00, (dataAcc[45]['x'] / 1.00)),
```

and here my array data from json using

```dart
dataAcc = json.decode(response.body);
```

```json
[
    {
        "id": 40,
        "time": 1614116099,
        "x": 10.27,
    },
    {
        "id": 39,
        "time": 1614116001,
        "x": 10.25,
    },
    {
        "id": 38,
        "x": 10.26,
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
i has been found solution for my problem, thanks all

```dart
 List<FlSpot> getAccData(String acc) {
    List<FlSpot> accList = [];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
      accList.add(FlSpot((i * 1.00), dataAcc[i][acc] / 1.00)); 
    }
    return accList;
  }
```